# Simple bash/script formatting tool, for paragraph text inside the script?

Tags: bash, unix, printf, echo

Context: You know how you type sentences in a word processor, and you don't have to do special formatting if you insert a new sentence in a paragraph, or make an existing sentence longer or shorter?

I'm writing some paragraphs to document what a given script does, inside it.  I want to be able to output that when the user invokes the script with a "-help", etc option, but not constantly have to adjust echo or printf statements everytime I add a sentence, or make one longer or shorter.   How can I do that?

I'm willing to make the output be 80 columns or some fixed width.

EDIT TO READER:  All answers are very informative I found.

Comment: So far the first answer isn't what I want.

Comment: ... the answer ignored the question, "document what a script does, inside it", and I write this comment only because of my seeming issue with stackoverflow is regarding provides "an answer", even if it is a "non-answer" -- isn't a correct answer matching the question -- people don't look nearly as much at the question anymore.  I'm going to write to the stackoverflow team regarding this unless you can add a comment here on how to fix that "stackoverflow usage issue".

Comment: If an answer doesn't work for you, ignore it. Or downvote it if you think it is really bad. However, I think that there is a legitimate assumption that people asking (eg.) bash questions have a minimum understanding of scripting and the ability to think independently, so that it is sufficient to say "You can use the `fold` utility", and not "Use `fold <<<"$description"` after you define the variable `$description`", which should be obvious once you know that the `fold` utility formats stdin to sdout. (It doesn't combine lines, so it's probably not what you want, but that's orthogonal.)

Comment: I thought with variables, like $description=, you need to put a "\" on every line of text to continue on, creating the same kind of issue.   Separately, I've experienced numerous times people rushing to answer, and then other people looking at the question much more slowly, because they think it's been answered.

Comment: In a shell quoted strings can contain newlines. A backslash-escaped newline is not a newline, though -- it is a line continuation indicator, and is removed during command parsing. It is true that people "read" too quickly; that applies both to questions and to answers, and even more so to documentation. But that is a disease of the modern era, and will not be solved in an SO comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the widely-available `fmt` utility.

If you have Gnu coreutils (which you almost certainly will if you are using Linux), then it you can use [the Gnu version](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fmt.1.html). There is a [very similar utility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fmt.1.html) available on many BSD systems, including Mac OS X.

Here's a simple example, which should work with either of those implementations. Note that the second paragraph is indented two spaces, and that indentation is preserved:

```
description="\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ornare leo non dolor porttitor
euismod. Cras
commodo, nisi vel gravida volutpat, enim turpis tempor eros, ut venenatis elit leo ut nunc. Nulla fermentum
ligula id tincidunt porttitor.

  Morbi ut massa vitae tortor rutrum
  gravida ut id nunc. Integer imperdiet pharetra augue, quis finibus justo
  luctus id. Phasellus a diam ac risus consequat pharetra. Cras
  lacinia neque
  sed ipsum euismod, non commodo felis facilisis.

Suspendisse luctus purus justo, sed iaculis lectus consequat nec. Etiam pretium ultricies
ligula, a pretium sapien facilisis eu. Nulla rhoncus viverra turpis a rutrum.
Cras eu porttitor urna. Duis nec metus vel nisi accumsan scelerisque. Cras lectus erat, mattis non mauris in, consectetur vulputate ipsum.
"
fmt -w 60 <<<"$description"
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Aenean ornare leo non dolor porttitor euismod. Cras
commodo, nisi vel gravida volutpat, enim turpis tempor
eros, ut venenatis elit leo ut nunc. Nulla fermentum ligula
id tincidunt porttitor.

  Morbi ut massa vitae tortor rutrum gravida ut id
  nunc. Integer imperdiet pharetra augue, quis finibus
  justo luctus id. Phasellus a diam ac risus consequat
  pharetra. Cras lacinia neque sed ipsum euismod, non
  commodo felis facilisis.

Suspendisse luctus purus justo, sed iaculis lectus
consequat nec. Etiam pretium ultricies ligula, a pretium
sapien facilisis eu. Nulla rhoncus viverra turpis a rutrum.
Cras eu porttitor urna. Duis nec metus vel nisi accumsan
scelerisque. Cras lectus erat, mattis non mauris in,
consectetur vulputate ipsum.
```

#### Incorporating the above in a script.

You can trivially add this into a script (thanks to @ninjaj for the suggestion about using tput to get the desired column width.)

```
#!/bin/bash
description=... # as above, not repeated for space

# Check to see if the first argument is a cry for help
if [[ $1 == -help ]]; then
  fmt -w $(tput cols) <<< "$description"
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: You can even use `fmt -w $(tput cols)` if you want paragraphs adjusted to the terminal width.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm actually using a basic cygwin install, and need to run to help a friend in need.  I'll look at your answer more in depth later.  Thank you.

Comment: Afaik, a basic cygwin install includes coreutils. An alternative to defining the `description` and then feeding it into `fmt` as a here-string would be to just use a here-doc in the call to `fmt`. I usually use the style indicated in the answer because I like the description to come at the head of the script, but tastes vary. See the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents).

Comment: Thanks Rici for all your help.  The fmt command with arguments you mentioned (and also @ninjaj, thanks), really works well.   I noticed I needed a -c option if I want to indent paragraphs, which is fine, if I end up with that style of indentation.

Answer (score 2):

The classic way to do this in UNIX/Linux is `fold`.  Here is an example:

```
     chicks ~ $ cat /etc/printcap  | fold -w 20
# This file was auto
matically generated 
by cupsd(8) from the
# /etc/cups/printers
.conf file.  All cha
nges to this file
# will be lost.
     chicks ~ $ cat /etc/printcap  | fold -w 40
# This file was automatically generated 
by cupsd(8) from the
# /etc/cups/printers.conf file.  All cha
nges to this file
# will be lost.
     chicks ~ $ cat /etc/printcap 
# This file was automatically generated by cupsd(8) from the
# /etc/cups/printers.conf file.  All changes to this file
# will be lost.
```

and to make it look more like it would in a script for Ray:

```
$ echo "Ray wants to see how this works inside of a script" | fold -w 20
Ray wants to see how
 this works inside o
f a script
$ cat foo 
echo "Ray wants to see how this works inside of a script" | fold -w 20
$ bash foo
Ray wants to see how
 this works inside o
f a script
$
```

Comment: In addition to `fold`, there are also similar tools worth looking at: `fmt` and `par`.

Comment: What if I want to include the text describing the script in the script, and not a separate file?   How do I add the text into the script, and then fold it when  user invokes the script with "-help"?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking, you want to include the text describing the script in the script itself, a simple method is to use a **heredoc** containing the description within the script and then simply test for `'-h'` or `'--help'` to display your description. You can gain quite a bit of flexibility by wrapping the **heredoc** in a function that can then serve as a general `usage` function to respond to help, display error conditions and set the exit code for any given situation.

A quick example is:

```
#!/bin/bash

maxval=127

usage() {

    local ecode=${2:-0}

    test -n "$1" && printf "\n %s\n" "$1" >&2

cat >&2 << MSG

 usage: ${0//*\//} srcdir tgtdir [maxname]  (maxname default: $maxval)

  This script will copy all files from 'srcdir' to 'tgtdir' with numeric names less 
  than 'maxname'.

 Options:

    -h  |  --help  program help (this file)
    -a  |  --all   copy all files from srcdir to tgtdir

MSG

    exit $ecode;
}

## respond to help
[ "$1" = -h -o "$1" = --help ] && usage

## example of error usage
[ -d "somedir" ] || usage "Error: directory does not exist" 2
```

Where everything between the `MSG` tags comprise the **heredoc**. The text can be as long or elaborate as you like it to be and is much easier to maintain than a series of `echo` or `printf` statements. While it will not re-flow the text for you as with `fmt` or `flow`, it is trivial to maintain and provides a simple alternative to using 3rd party tools.

**Example Responding to --help**

```
$ bash usage.sh --help

 usage: usage.sh srcdir tgtdir [maxname]  (maxname default: 127)

  This script will copy all files from 'srcdir' to 'tgtdir' with numeric names less
  than 'maxname'.

 Options:

    -h  |  --help  program help (this file)
    -a  |  --all   copy all files from srcdir to tgtdir
```

**Example Showing Error Condition**

```
$ bash usage.sh

 Error: directory does not exist

 usage: usage.sh srcdir tgtdir [maxname]  (maxname default: 127)

  This script will copy all files from 'srcdir' to 'tgtdir' with numeric names less
  than 'maxname'.

 Options:

    -h  |  --help  program help (this file)
    -a  |  --all   copy all files from srcdir to tgtdir

$ echo $?
2
```

Comment: Thanks David for this alternative and how to use it succinctly.  Rici pointed to this as an option to in the Bash manual, but there is no example there, and seeing how to use it with help and error conditions is great.  I'm writing a few scripts so I think I will try both solutions.  How does one vote for two answers as being correct? ;-)

Comment: You bet. Though not every one of my scripts gets a full-blow `usage()` function, for those that do, I have not found a simpler or more flexible approach. Yes, you might have to reformat a line if what you add wraps, but that is small potatoes compared to all the formatting and variable expansion control you get using a heredoc. Maybe you can take a couple of the ideas and build the next great script intro for usage functions, etc.. If you do, I would love to see it. Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: Hi David I'm leaning to "your approach" more and more.  I thought perhaps both approaches can be combined (simply added) if one has a longer paragraphs in a second part of the usage area.  I'm pretty new to doing anything but the very basics in a script so I'm sure there are better ways to combine both ...

Comment: That's the beauty of scripting, there are usually several ways to accomplish whatever it is you need to do. As you get further into it, you generally balance simplicity/efficiency/robustness (error checking) in arriving at a solution. 'simplicity' generally means using native bash/sh capabilities and avoiding spawning additional subshells with 3rd party tools. (but, sometimes they provide a better solution) I've messed with many ways of doing what you are attempting over the years, and always end up coming back to a simple heredoc in a `usage()` function. Good luck.